# Create instance of a generic without knowing T

Tags: c#, generics

I'm currently developping a grid for MVC that works through data annotations.

So, I have an interface that converts an objects from a given type to another type:

```
public interface ITypeConverter<in T>
{
    #region Propreties

    bool IsValid { get; }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    string Convert(T propertyValue);

    #endregion
}
```

If I would like all my properties to be displayed in uppercase, I can do it like this:

```
public class UppercaseConverter : ITypeConverter<string>
{
    #region ITypeConverter Members

    public bool IsValid { get { return true; } }

    public string Convert(string propertyValue)
    {
        return propertyValue.ToString().ToUpper();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Now, in my class that creates the grid, I would like to create an instance of the TypeConverter.

```
if (gridColumnAttribute.TypeConverter != null)
{ TypeConverter = (ITypeConverter<object>)Activator.CreateInstance(gridColumnAttribute.TypeConverter); }
```

Off course, this doens't work, since I'm using ITypeConverter where it should be a string.

But I don't know the type of T in advance.

Any idea on how I can create an instance of it and execute the method "Convert"?

Answer (score 2):

Can't you determine the TypeConverter that should be used by using a TypeDescriptor ?

```
TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
```

Something like that.

Comment: I'm new to TypeDescription. Can you edit your approach with how to use it in my solution please?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how good is this approach, but this should help.

I'd introduce a non generic interface with a `Convert` method, and a helper abstract class as well.

```
public interface ITypeConverter
{
    string Convert(object propertyValue);
}

public interface ITypeConverter<in T> : ITypeConverter
{
    bool IsValid { get; }
    string Convert(T propertyValue);
}

public abstract class TypeConverterBase<T> : ITypeConverter<T>
{
    public string Convert(object propertyValue)
    {
        //Helper method just to call right overload of generic method.
        return Convert((T) propertyValue);
    }

    public abstract bool IsValid { get; }
    public abstract string Convert(T propertyValue);
}

public class UppercaseConverter : TypeConverterBase<string>
{
    public override bool IsValid { get { return true; } }

    public override string Convert(string propertyValue)
    {
        return propertyValue.ToString().ToUpper();
    }
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Type type = typeof(UppercaseConverter);
    var converter = (ITypeConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    var converted = converter.Convert("hello");
    Console.WriteLine(converted);//Prints HELLO
}
```

Comment: why do you need the `public string Convert(object propertyValue)`? Isn't `Convert(T propertyValue);` sufficient?

Comment: @Default You forgot that OP doesn't know what is `T`, so we may need to use reflection or `dynamic`. Alternatively I used type unsafe `Convert(object propertyValue)`.

Comment: Ahh, I see. for the `(ITypeConverter)` cast. Clever :)